# I am getting error when publishing a page

Tags: publishing

> Attempting to deploy a binary 34846 to a different location while still in use by deployed items that are not being redeployed in this transaction: [tcd:pub[146]/pagemeta[34874], tcd:pub[146]/pagemeta[35330], tcd:pub[146]/pagemeta[34817], tcd:pub[146]/pagemeta[35306],

Comment: This is answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856708/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already

Comment: As Nickoli said please first try to search the answer on google, tridion forum instead of putting same question on forums, its only increase count questions

Comment: Nash and nickoli, above said thread is taking about duplicate binaries, this is different error message, I have checked that thread already and it was not issue in my case. I have only one binary(image), it is used in different components, when I try to publish it is giving this error.

Comment: Is it like the same image which have been published already have been manually kept open on the server by any of the user of server and then we are trying to re-publishing the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you get this error message in your specific case. But what I can do is explain what situation the error message is trying to prevent.

Say that:

- You have a multimedia component that has image called photo1.jpg
- You have two components that somehow refer to that MMC (e.g. in a rich-text field)
- You publish both components, which of course also publishes the photo1.jpg.
- You upload a new image into the multimedia component, named photo2.jpg
- You republish only one component

That last action will result (in your case) in a deployment action that updates the content of one component presentation and updates the photo by **removing photo1.jpg and writing the new image to photo2.jpg**.

If the deployer executed this action, it would result in a broken image link from the other component presentation. If also can't deploy just the single component presentation, since that would then contain a broken link to photo2.jpg. And it also can't leave both photo1.jpg and photo2.jpg, since each multimedia component can have only file in the broker (ignoring variants for the moment).

So in this scenario, you've essentially given the deployer an impossible task. It informs you of that fact by throwing an exception with the error message you see: you're trying to rename a binary that is still being used by content that you are not updating.

Normally Tridion's publisher will prevent this situation from occurring, by ensuring all Components that refer to the Multimedia Component will be re-published when the Multimedia Component gets published. This is a large part of the resolving phase that you may hear of and it often explains why Tridion ends up publishing more items than you might initially expect: it is **ensuring the integrity of all relations in the published content**.

Sorry for the long story. I hope it helps you (or someone else) to realize what is going wrong.